# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/springframework/http/HttpEntity

Tags: android, spring

To fix following error meassage

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter**

I added "**spring-web-3.0.2.jar**" to build path of android application and selected that jar in "order and Export" in JavaBuildpath.(properties->buildpath->order and Export).

After adding this perticular(spring-web-3.0.2.jar) It fixed "**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError**" but It is throwing fallowing error when try to run my application.

**Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/springframework/http/HttpEntity;
 Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/springframework/http/HttpEntity;**

What I am doing Worng?Is it because of multiple jar which contains Lorg/springframework/http/HttpEntity.

Follwing are the jar I added in my project.

1. simple-xml-2.7
2. spring-android-auth-1.0.1.RELEASE
3. spring-android-core-1.0.1.RELEASE
4. spring-android-rest-template-1.0.1.RELEASE
5. spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE

How can I fix this issue?Any help greatly appricated.

Answer (score 2):

I think that spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE is not needed, try to remove it and check again. That error is because the Dalvik Virtual machine found two classes with same name and package.

org.springframework.http.HttpEntity exists in Spring Android and in Spring-web.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion,Which I tried before also,It gives me class not error,Which I mentioned in questions.If I add it gives me following error.                                                 "Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/springframework/http/HttpEntity; Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/springframework/http/HttpEntity;"

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this post, it seems to be related, specifically Roy's answer

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/android/743289-importing-android-spring-with-gradle-cause-error-mutiple-dex-files

> The Spring for Android rest-template and core artifacts do not have a dependency on spring core or any Spring Framework library. However, the auth dependency does, along with Spring Social. You can exclude globally like the following, then you don't have to repeat the exclusion for each dependency. I also agree about the frustration with the packagingOptions in the newer Android Gradle plugin versions. It really should support a wildcard so you don't have to declare all those individually. Hopefully, Google will add that in the future. 
>   Code:

```
configurations.compile {
      exclude module: 'spring-core'
      exclude module: 'spring-web'
      exclude module: 'commons-logging'
  }
```